# Read constants from .INI file

Tags: vb.net, file, settings, connection-string, ini

I want to write my connection string and other constants in a Settings.INI file.

My ini file:

```
[ConnectionString]
Con="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

How can I read the connection string in VB.net when I need it?
In ASP.net it's all simpler with app.config. But I am working on windows forms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Winforms can use app.config and it is easy to use as in a web app. Why do you want to use this obsolete format?

Comment: Correct. You can use the app.config to store the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`My.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx) object in VB.NET. You can also use `app.config` in VB.NET as you would in ASP.NET.